# Is there a way to open a blender file from 4.0 into 3.4?

Tags: rendering, animation, shaders

I am trying to open a file I made in Blender 4.0 into version 3.4. I find the shaders tab easier to understand but it won't let me open the file in 3.4. When I go into the open file, it just closes blender. Is there any way for me to open it in version 3.4?

Comment: I usually do this by opening a fresh 3.X file, then by "appending" from 4.Y file. But things are lost in the process...

Comment: How do I do this? Are there any videos that can tell me?

Comment: Open a new file in Blender 3, then File > Append, select the file, go into the Object folder, load everything

Comment: It just crashes my blender @moonboots

Comment: Version 3.4 isn't supported now. What happens if you try to open it in the current LTS version 3.6.8?

Comment: For a few more details see the 4.0 release notes here: https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.0/ This is taken from the Compatibility section in them: "Blender 3.6 LTS can read files saved with 4.0, but earlier versions cannot. Blender 3.6 LTS will save meshes in a format compatible with older versions of Blender, so it can be used as conversion tool if needed."